# Entity Validation API: Retrieve parent field entity while validating

Tags: 8, entities

I'm using the Drupal 8 [Entity Validation API](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-api/entity-validation-api). I've implemented my `Constraint` and `ConstraintValidator` classes and added them as a constraint against the relevant entity field.

If I understand the `validate` method [signature](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-api/entity-validation-api/providing-a-custom-validation-constraint#s-step-2-create-the-validation-for-the-constraint) for `ConstraintValidator` correctly, I'm given a list of fields (`$items`) and the constraint (`$constraint`). However, I need to retrieve the parent entity in my logic.

How can I get the parent entity while with the validation API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using [FieldItemList::getEntity](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21FieldItemList.php/function/FieldItemList%3A%3AgetEntity/8.7.x) like in this core validator:

*Drupal\Core\Validation\Plugin\Validation\Constraint\UniqueFieldValueValidator:*

```
class UniqueFieldValueValidator extends ConstraintValidator {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function validate($items, Constraint $constraint) {
    if (!$item = $items->first()) {
      return;
    }
    $field_name = $items->getFieldDefinition()->getName();
    /** @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity */
    $entity = $items->getEntity();
```

The first argument of a validate method is of mixed type. For the Drupal Entity Validation API this can be a field value, a field item list or an entity, depending on where you add the constraint.